# Getting the result of OPENSSL SHA1() function into an ARRAY

Tags: c, openssl, sha1

i'm working on a project and i have some problems.I have searched but can not find any satisfied answer.

i have a huge file consists of 0 and 1s.
i'm getting 1024 (my chunk) bits into an array chunk and after that i apply SHA1() function which is implemented in  openssl/sha.h library.

> char chunk[1024];
>   while((fgets(chunk,1024,fp))!=NULL)

My intention is that my file can consist of same chunks and i want to count how many chunks are same.

After i get 1024 bits in my array chunk i apply :

unsigned char obuf[20];

> SHA1(chunk,strlen(chunk), obuf); 
>   function to get the result of the hash function.

here how SHA1 function works

> unsigned char *SHA1(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n,unsigned char *md);

after that i want to store my hash function result in an array.After i read all of my file, i'll use this array to compare if there are same hash results or not, by this way i can start my project.But i stuck in this point. i can not put the result obuf to an array.

i tried :
memcopy()
strcopy()
or just myarray[N][20]=obuf; etc.

if you suggest some way, i'll be happy thanks.

so the biggest problem is that finding the  how many hashes are unique ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you say that your chunks of input file are of size **1024** - however this line will read at most **1023** characters from your file (it uses one space for the null terminator):

```
char chunk[1024]; while((fgets(chunk,1024,fp))!=NULL)
```

(I think `fread` might well be closer to what you're trying to do here)

Secondly, you can just do something like:

```
#define MAX_CHUNKS 1000

unsigned char chunk[1024];
unsigned char obuf[MAX_CHUNKS][20];
int chunk_n = 0;

while (fread(chunk, sizeof chunk, 1, fp) > 0 && chunk_n < MAX_CHUNKS)
{
    SHA1(chunk, sizeof chunk, obuf[chunk_n++]);
}

/* Now have chunk_n SHA1s stored in obuf[0] through obuf[chunk_n -1] */
```

Comment: i'm just trying it, it makes sense. You are right  this line will read at most 1023 but i can modify my problem is just putting it into array...

Comment: You will need to use the function `memcmp(obuf[i], obuf[j], 20)` to compare the hashes.  `memcmp` will return `0` if the two hashes are equal.  I think you might need to brush up on your C basics...

Comment: it's not as easy as you think, cuz let's think my hashes are [5,4,5,4,3,3,2,1,5,2] it's hard to implement the function using memcmp.(beginner in c)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use C?  containers with unique keys and so on are a lot easier in e.g. python or perl.  Or even C++.  In C, the easiest thing is a naive linear search, but a hash table would prob. be faster.

Comment: It's not as complicated as you think. Finding unique elements IS comparing, at least to begin with. caf definitely has pointed you in the right direction.